# Request.getParts is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I would like to use JSF native fileupload component. With AJAX if possible. But I cannot get it to work.

**FileUpload**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}" required="true"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.importFile()}"/>
</h:form>
```

I thought the following error should not be present using JSF 2.2.

> `Request.getParts` is called without multipart configuration. Either add
>   a `@MultipartConfig` to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to
>   web.xml

**Environment**

- Glassfish 4.1
- Mojarra 2.2.4
- Primefaces 5.0

Comment: GF 4.1 ships with Mojarra 2.2.7. Did you manually downgrade/override it?

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the Multipart config to your web.xml? There really shouldn't be any need to since FacesServlet in Mojarra 2.2 does have the appropriate annotation, but to eliminate any config-related issue, you could add the multipart config to your web.xml

Comment: @kolossus No i did not had `multipart-config` in `web.xml`. After adding it it works now, thanks! @BalusC yes because of some other issues.

Comment: @djmj - I'll be posting that as an answer then.

Comment: You shouldn't have the need for `<multipart-config>` in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some [not apparent] reason, the `@MultipartConfig` that was added to `FacesServlet` for JSF-2.2 is not kicking in for you. As a result, it's now necessary for you to [manually add the multipart configuration to your web.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html) like so:

```
 <multipart-config>
      <location>/tmp</location>
      <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
 </multipart-config>
```

Comment: I had no look at mojarra source, but was `@MultipartConfig` added to mojarra after 2.2.4?

Comment: [Since at least 2.2.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.2/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java#FacesServlet) @djmj

Comment: So it must not be the result of me downgrading JSF. Still accepted as valid answer.

Comment: My mistake @djmj. I missed the part where you stated your JSF version. I'll edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: It was in [since 2.2.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java/) already. OP's runtime classpath was just being dirty which might have more other side effects. This is therefore not a valid solution but a temporary workaround. The whole thing works just out the box in GF 4.1 without any changes.

Comment: How do i clean my classpath?

Comment: You should run [jboss' TattleTale](http://tattletale.jboss.org) on your project deployment to get a report on duplicate jars and other environmental problems @djmj